# Spring and layout views

Tags: java, spring, velocity, tiles

I'm new to Spring (not to Java) and I just can't wrap my head around all the tiles stuff. What I want to do is to have a layout with a placeholder for JavaScript includes. 
In .Net I can define a master page which contains some content placeholders.

Layout.Master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="javascripts" runat="server" />
</head>
<body>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="content" runat="server" />
</body>
</html>
```

In the view for the action I can then define how the placeholder should be replaced.

index.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content" ContentPlaceHolderID="content" runat="server">
    This is the body content
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="javascripts" runat="server">
    <script src="foo.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

How can I do that in Spring? I have seen that VelocityLayoutView has a similar functionality but I couldn't figure out how to define content for placeholders from within a tile.

Comment: try [this link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/07/spring-3-mvc-tiles-plugin-tutorial-example-eclipse.html)

Comment: that's almost what I'm looking for. But is there a possibility to define the content for the title attribute from within another tile without having to configure anything in the tiles definition?

Comment: yes you can, how - sorry you'll have to look it up, i don't remember off hand :-(

Comment: @Mato give an example of what you want to do

Comment: @soulcheck waht I want is that every tile can insert javascripts into the page header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a templating engine with support for template inheritance and defining arbitrary placeholders.

I don't know of many that do (in java world there's a bias towards template composition and that's what plain jsp:include, tiles etc do).

[StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) supports inheritance and there is a [plugin](https://github.com/tomcz/spring-stringtemplate) for spring that adds support for ST, but I don't know if the plugin supports template inheritance and ST inheritance AFAIK doesn't let you define placeholders.

Another option is [Jangod](http://www.jangod.org)

Looks like it does what you're looking for. 
For example (taken from their website):

Base template

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}Jangod ????{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            {% block footer %}
            © Copyright 2010
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Template, which extends base template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Hello {{user.name}}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Recencies</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for post in posts %}
            <li>{{post.title}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

It has [support for Spring MVC](http://www.jangod.org/downloads.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am using Apache Tiles for the same problem and it's really simple to use...
just google Apache tiles + Spring to see how to wire them together ( a simple xml config )

after that

Just create a Layout.jsp with your main layout, the includes you mentioned.

```
<html>
  <head><title>Tiles Quickstart</title><head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      Welcome to Tiles 101
    </div>

    <div id="body">
      Tiles 101 body content.
    </div>

    <div id=footer">
      &#169; 2007, Apache Software Foundation
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

After that setup a tiles.xml with the mapping to substitute the includes with some valid pages and leave the header and footer as default( I do that what )

like this

```
<tiles-definitions>
  <definition name="header" template="/fragments/header.jsp">
  </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

the you just need to give Spring the String for that JSP, if it's called

you have a full tutorial here [Apache Tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/quickstart/index.html)